# Unable to run Scala code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am very new to scala and I am trying to run a simple code. How ever I am getting this prompt asking for main class and I dont know to get around it. I have attached a screenshot. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

**EDIT**

I have removed package greeting and yet the problem persists
[image]

My workspace loks like this

[image]

When I try to run it looks like this
[image]

Comment: Type the path for the main class.

Comment: I would wholeheartedly recommend using IntelliJ for Scala development. There is a community edition which is free and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse your `package` in your Scala file should match your folder structure, otherwise it will not find your main.

So either put the scala file in a folder called `greeter` or remove `package greeter`.

I am pretty sure this is a bug in the Scala IDE.

Comment: I have edited my question with suggested corrections

Comment: Judging by the '*' before your file I guess you haven't saved it. Can you save and try again?

Comment: Even after saving and restarting the IDE if I want to run it as a scala application it is asking for Main Class

Comment: Wait a minute, you also removed `extends App`. Can you readd that?

Comment: I added that. Yet when I run it as Scala Application it is asking for Main Class

Comment: Can you right click in you Scala file and look under `Run As` it should say `Scala Application`

Comment: Run as gives Java Applet and Java application. I have attached the screenshot

Comment: You right clicked the project, and you right click in the Scala file.

Comment: Sorry for the error. I have updated it. There is no option of Scala Application when I right click the Scala File. When I click on Run Configuration I see Scala Application but clicking that brings me back to the initial problem

Comment: In your second screenshot in notice the Scala library is missing, can you dubbel check that one?

Comment: I have updated my final screen shot by adding scala library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105827/discussion-between-pim-verkerk-and-rajarshi-bhadra).